# Optimizing Mysql role management query in web-application?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, query-optimization

Let me start off by the structure of mysql

**Table structure for groups**

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `org_id` (`org_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `groups_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`org_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Table structure for groups_perm**

```
CREATE TABLE `group_perm` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `permission_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `permission_id` (`permission_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `group_perm_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `group_perm_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `perm` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Table structure for perm**

```
CREATE TABLE `perm` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `namespace` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `default_perm` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `app_id` (`app_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `perm_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`app_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Now i am running a couple of sql query when a new group is created in following format

```
[1ms] select count(*) from user where username= ?
[290ms] insert into user (username, active, is_organization, owner_id) values ( ? , 1, 1, ?);
[144ms] insert into groups (title, org_id) values ('default', ? )
[199ms] insert into group_perm (permission_id, group_id) select id, ? from perm where perm.default_perm=1;
[31ms] insert into user_group (user_id, group_id, org_id) values ( ? , ? , ?)
```

As you can see that running all queries on a single route is bad from user experience side and adds up to latency. I know an option would be to push that as a background job but i was really interested to know if somehow i can optimize the queries itself to execute faster.

#### Important stuff to know

1. `User` and `organization` are stored in same table with `is_organization` flag set and in case of `organization` referencing to same table.
2. The 4th query mentioned needs to be dynamic as default permissions to be given to new organization can change over time.
3. I would prefer to keep foreign key index but am open to hear out any other suggestions as well.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]--that includes *complete* DDL & DML. Read other Qs & As re SQL/MySQL [tag:query-optimization] to see good Qs--eg include query plans etc. Read the manual re indexes & optimizations--eg MySQL FK declaration implicitly indexes. What does "running all queries on a single route" mean? What parts of the system is that time spent it? (Always do everything you know you want at once--eg via transaction/procedure.) What concurrent queries are run while these are? Why tag MariaDB?